# How to understand "survive contact with" in this context?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, parts-of-speech

> As the closest bead of light moved nearer to Harry's wand tip, the wood beneath his fingers grew so hot he feared it would burst into flame. The closer that bead moved, the harder Harry's wand vibrated; he was sure his wand would not ***survive contact with*** it; it felt as though it was about to shatter under his fingers -

I guess "*survive contact with*" here means *his wand would be broken/shattered once contacting with the bead*. I'm wondering if "*survive contact with*" is a set phrase? The closest one I got: [no plan survives contact with the enemy](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/no+plan+survives+contact+with+the+enemy). It might be slightly different. I'd also like to know what part of speech "**contact**" is, *noun* or *verb*?

Comment: What made you think it's an idiom? Have you looked up the word *survive* in a dictionary? *Contact* is a noun in that sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not **survive contact with** a high-voltage power line.

Superman can **survive contact with** a high-voltage power line.

Notice that the preposition depends on the preceding noun:

> Some bacteria cannot survive **exposure to** sunlight.

Contact with, exposure to.

That which was survived is that which did not kill the survivor.

> He survived the surgical operation.

Sometimes **survive** is used as hyperbole, figuratively:

> He survived the midterm exam.

Comment: So, it should read as: [Superman can survive] [contact with a high-voltage power line.] Can it be paraphrased as: Superman can survive when contact with a high-voltage power line.?

Comment: Wondering if "contact with.." is an object of 'survive' or its complement?

Comment: @dan As userr2684291 remarked in his or her comment at the top of the page, **contact** is a noun in the OP.  So in this most recent paraphrase of yours, "when contact with a high-voltage power line" there is a grammatical error: your clause is missing a verb.  "... when contact *is made* with a high-voltage power line".

Comment: **contact with a high-voltage power line** is a noun-phrase and is the direct object of the verb **survive**.